# How to mock @Autowired HttpServletRequest in Service Test class?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

In my service class i have @Autowired HttpServletRequest and using the same object in my service method but for that service method test class i am not able to mock HttpServletRequest object in my test method please check below code. I am getting Null Pointer exception for request object

```java
    @Component("someServiceClass")
    public class SomeServiceClassImpl implements SomeServiceClass {

        @Autowired
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @Autowired
        private HttpServletResponse response;

        @Override
        public void method(String id) {
            String param = request.getParameter("param");
// Here i am getting request object as null
        }

    }
```

```java
    public class SomeServiceClassImplTest {

        @Mock
        private HttpServletRequest request;

        @Mock
        private HttpServletResponse response;

        @InjectMocks
        private SomeServiceClassImpl someServiceClass;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void methodTest() {
            Mockito.when(request.getParameter(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("dm");

        }

    }
```

Comment: above code works fine. its `@InjectMocks`  not `@InjectMock`

Answer (score 1):

Is the setup() method getting called?

Shouldn't you add a `@RunWith` annotation to specify a runner which will execute method marked as `@Before`?

For eg., you can mark your class with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your class misses the `@RunWith` annotation, so the mocks are not initialized

add `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` (or `SpringRunner`), it will solve it.

Generally speaking, I think it is better to autowire with constructor and not on the fields. I know it's a matter of style, but doing this will resolve the need to use `InjectMocks` or any other reflection based tools.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and when i added @WebAppConfiguration, it was solved.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SomeServiceClassImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeServiceClassImpl someServiceClass;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void methodTest() {
        Mockito.when(request.getParameter(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("dm");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you initialized these mocked objects ?, otherwise you got Null Pointer exception

```
  @Before public void initMocks() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

}